# How do I find the joint pdf of the joint distribution X, Y, Z

Tags: probability-distributions

Six cards are to be drawn from an ordinary deck of cards.
$X$ is the number of low ($1$-$5$) black suited cards drawn
$Y$ is the number of high ($6$-$10$) red suited cards drawn
$Z$ is the number of face cards drawn.
What is the joint pdf of $X, Y, Z$?

I know that the number of ways to choose for $X$ is $10Cx$
The number of ways to choose for $Y$ is $10Cy$
And the number of ways to choose for $Z$ is $12Cz$.

I know I have to multiply all $(10Cx)(10Cy)(12Cz)$ then divide it by $(52C6)$.

But it seems like I'm missing out something else...

Comment: You are missing that it is possible to select some cards that are not low black, high red, or faces.

Answer (score 1):

$P(X=x,Y=y,Z=z) = \dfrac{{10\choose x}{10\choose y}{12\choose z}{20\choose (6-x-y-z)}}{{52\choose 6}}$

This is the joint pdf of X,Y,Z

Comment: Why is there a 20C(6-x-y-z)?

Comment: That term shall not be there if you are sure that x+y+z = 6.  But the problem does not guarantee that.

Comment: @Yuumi, ways to select the rest of the hand from cards that are *not* low black, high red, or faces.